# How to resize Text of QLabel displayed on other screen resolutions

Tags: c++, qt, size, screen-resolution, qlabel

We have a GUI created with Qt Creator. When we use this GUI on different machines with higher screen-resolution, some of the text sizes of our QLabels do not resize as we want.
In the below example we have 3 QLables but only the second ( Number of…) and third Label ( Fract. of work… ) resizes correctly. The first label ( Enable user… ) does not. ( the second label is disabled as well)

[image]

The only difference between the first and the second/third QLabel in the property-section I can see is that the property Point size is bold for the second/third QLabel but not bold for the first QLabel.

The first QLabel:
[image]

The second/third QLabel:
[image]

Since this is the only difference I can see I think the behaviour is somehow connected to this property.AS the behaviour of the third label would be better for us, how come it is different an d more important **how/where do I set this property to the “bold state”**

Comment: First of all, since you are observing this on different machines, are those machine the same architectures of the original one ? If not, did you recompile the program for the target architecture ? If you did and still observe this behaviour, we would need a minimal, complete and reproducible example to be able to help you any further.

Comment: This was mentioned in another similar question this week but I have not tried: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize)